# How to remove optional value for int, double, float in Firestore?

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve a number type/value for my Total from my firestore, so far my code has been working, its just showing "$optional value: 30" in place of `price.text = "$\(product.price)` where it should be showing "$30".

Ive used INT, FLOAT, & DOUBLE (whether it be ?/!) and still getting the same results in the label showing "$Optional value: 30"

I just want to get rid of the "optional value" in the pricelabel when using the simulator

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class List {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var price: Float!                                       

    init(id: String,
         name: String,
         price: Float!) {                                             

         self.id = id
         self.name = name
         self.price = price
     }

     convenience init(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        let id = dictionary["id"] as? String ?? ""
        let name = dictionary["name"] as? String ?? ""
        let price =  dictionary["price"] as? Float               

        self.init(id: id,
                  name: name,
                  price: price)
    }

}
```

---

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ListCell: UITableViewCell {

    weak var list: List!

    @IBOutlet weak var productName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var price: UILabel!

    func configure(withList list: List) {
        productName.text = product.name
        price.text = "$\(product.price)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `price` as non-optional

```
var price: Float 

...

init(id: String,
     name: String,
     storeName: String,
     brand: String,
     category: String,
     strain: String,
     price: Float) {
```

and assign a default value like the other properties

```
let price =  dictionary["price"] as? Float ?? 0.0
```

To display the price value with maximum 2 fractional digits use a `NumberFormatter`

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
price.text = "$\(formatter.string(for: product.price)!)"
```

---

And don't misuse `String(describing`, it's redundant anyway as `brand` and `name` **are** strings

```
productName.text = "\(product.brand): \(product.name)"
```

Comment: it works! but how would I remove the decimal point in it since it now shows "$30.0"

Comment: You need to add a [`NumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter)

Comment: I don't want to be a pain to you but im still kinda new to this since ive only been doing this for about 3 months, But how would I use number formate to do it

Comment: its giving me that optional value again :'(

Comment: That's impossible if `price` is declared as non-optional

Comment: im weirded out as much as you are, but that's what it is showing at the moment... sorry, if it helps.. you're the best for taking the time to help me out

Comment: My bad, you have to unwrap the value, answer updated.